# Is there a way to create your own html tag in HTML5?

Tags: html

I want to create something like

```
<menu>
    <lunch>
        <dish>aaa</dish>
        <dish>bbb</dish>
    </lunch>
    <dinner>
        <dish>ccc</dish>
    </dinner>
</menu>
```

Can it be done in HTML5?
I know I can do it with

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <ul id="lunch">
            <li class="dish">aaa</li>
            <li class="dish">bbb</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul id="dinner">
            <li class="dish">ccc</li>
        </ul>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

but it is so much less readable :(

Comment: what are you trying to do? what you're after could probably just be solved by `div`s with classnames

Comment: You might also look at XML+XSLT to see if that fits your need better. That allows you to transform (the xslt part) one XML document (yours) into another (html)

Comment: Wow I posted this a long time ago : ) Given how well getElementById() performs compared to grabbing by tag name, and how things like SVG provide a whole new set of functionality along with their semantics, I think custom tags have less uses than I may have originally thought. Thanks everyone for all the thoughtful comments and answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are custom elements valid HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5)

Comment: Also [Is there a way to create your own tags in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5)

Comment: It's a good summary:

https://matthewjamestaylor.com/custom-tags

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can use custom tags in browsers, although they won’t be HTML5 (see [Are custom elements valid HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5) and [the HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#elements)).

Let's assume you want to use a custom tag element called **`<stack>`**. Here's what you should do...

**STEP 1**

Normalize its attributes in your CSS Stylesheet (think css reset) - 
Example:

```
 stack{display:block;margin:0;padding:0;border:0; ... }
```

**STEP 2**

To get it to work in old versions of Internet Explorer, you need to append this script to the head (Important if you need it to work in older versions of IE!):

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]> 
 <script> document.createElement("stack"); </script>
 <![endif]-->
```

---

Then you can use your custom tag freely.

```
<stack>Overflow</stack>
```

Feel free to set attributes as well...

```
<stack id="st2" class="nice"> hello </stack>
```

Comment: Absolutely correct.  Not a fantastic idea.  But absolutely correct.
You could make a whole army of your own tags on your page, and make them all backwards-compatible with IE6, just by adding an array of all of the tag names you want to use, and then creating each one inside a for-loop, in your page head, before you start using any of them.

That's how the html5shim works in the first place.

Just be prepared to put effort into styling them in old-IE.

Also, while I'd say this is okay for internal-use, it's not really how I'd want to teach people to do things.  At all.

Comment: I agree, writing your own tags is not for the faint of heart. Make sure you test it thoroughly. I would like to say one thing though... don't write CSS for IE6. Completely waste of resources and enables further use of such a horrible product that not even Microsoft endorses.

Comment: @TimothyPerez Just curious, on what browsers did you test this method?

Comment: @alexwells - Chrome, FF, Safari, IE 7-9

Comment: Very important note: Although *browsers* support creating a custom element, it's not officially supported by the HTML5 standard. **Technically**, custom elements are verboten. You can do it, and make your HTML look all nice and semantically important, but you are breaking the standard if you do -- if you care. :)

Comment: Sometimes... new standards need to be set. ;-)

Comment: Back in the days when all this mattered and "doctype" had a meaning you could download the doctype definition, modify it and then reference it on your site (or use it to validate in a custom parser, like Xerxes).

Comment: Conventions exist for the purposes of communication, and since marked up content like HTML is used for communication, it's critical to follow the convention that everyone else understands.  It's great to create your own tags that work, but if no one else understands what you're talking about, it doesn't have much value.  Do yourself a favour and stick to the standard.

Comment: If I skip Step 2, only old browsers will be affected but new browsers will work fine, I assume? This `Important` makes me distrustful :-)

Comment: Even if this method _does_ work, it's a potential booby trap.  Consider what happens when a ``<menu>`` tag is officially defined as part of HTML:  all your pages that use your home-made tag are likely to break.  And even if they don't, anyone looking at your source is going to be very confused by your unusual use of the tag, not realizing that it _isn't_ the HTML tag that they are now familiar with.  I pity the people that will have to maintain these pages several years from now.

Comment: One key advantage is intrinsic documentation especially at the closing end. It would be quite obvious if you missed a closing tag!

Answer (score 32):

I'm not so sure about these answers. As I've just read:
"CUSTOM TAGS HAVE ALWAYS BEEN ALLOWED IN HTML."

http://www.crockford.com/html/

The point here being, that HTML was based on SGML. Unlike XML with its doctypes and schemas, HTML does not become invalid if a browser doesn't know a tag or two. Think of <marquee>. This has not been in the official standard. So while using it made your HTML page "officially unapproved", it didn't break the page either.

Then there is <keygen>, which was Netscape-specific, forgotten in HTML4 and rediscovered and now specified in HTML5.
And also we have custom tag attributes now, like data-XyZzz="..." allowed on all HTML5 tags.

So, while you shouldn't invent a whole custom unspecified markup salad of your own, it's not exactly forbidden to have custom tags in HTML. That is however, unless you want to send it with an +xml Content-Type or embed other XML namespaces, like SVG or MathML. This applies only to SGML-confined HTML.

Comment: Also of interest here:

http://www.librador.com/2009/10/20/Styling-undefined-tag-names-in-HTML/

"You can use any tag name in HTML, and it will be part of the DOM and can be styled."

Comment: “So while using it made your html page "official unapproved", it didn't break the page either.” — um, try styling your invented elements in Internet Explorer. It won’t work. You might not consider that broken, but the fact that custom tags are invalid and don’t work in Internet Explorer, I don’t see how you can argue they’re “allowed”.

Comment: Or how Douglas Crockford can either. Yeah, Crockford. I’m calling you out. *Bring it*, buddy.

Comment: I mean, he doesn’t back up his statement with anything. Just because Douglas Crockford said it, it doesn’t mean it’s true.

Comment: This is what [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#notes-invalid-docs) say: "This specification does not define how conforming user agents handle ... elements ... not specified in this document. \[...] we recommend the following behavior:
 If a user agent encounters an element it does not recognize, it should try to render the element's content. \[...] authors and users must not rely on specific error recovery behavior" - IMHO this means that Crockfor is wrong, for once.

Comment: why not create a markup salad of your own? What are the consequences of doing that?

Comment: I like the way the person that published that webpage speaks as though his fixes have been employed already. Must be really confident in his idea. :P

Comment: Check out angular.js framework. Lets you create your own html <components>. http://angularjs.org/#/list

Comment: @Costa: HTML is useful because it's a set of agreed meanings for tags. For example, browsers make links clickable because we've agreed (via [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/spec.html)) that the `<a>` tag is a link to another page. You can create your own markup salad, but it won't have meaning to anyone else except yourself. For a given purpose, that might be fine, but you're not really using HTML any more.

Comment: All programming applies meanings and functionality to tags, classes and functions etc. However this reasoning does not in any way restrict a programmer from creating their own respective names for tags, classes or functions.  The important point is "respect the namespace" and check future versions do not implement the name you have used.  From the comments so far all that can be said in certainty is that this might be 'frowned upon' by some, at least until a concrete issue is reported.

Comment: Heh, that link isn't even about HTML as we know it. : "The new language I am proposing is not totally compatible with HTML 4 [...] This is my proposal for a kinder, gentler HTML 5."

Answer (score 6):

I just want to add to the previous answers that there is a meaning to use only two-words tags for custom elements.
They should never be standardised.

---

For example, you want to use the tag `<icon>`, because you don't like `<img>`, and you don't like `<i>` neither...

Well, keep in mind that you're not the only one. Maybe in the future, w3c and/or browsers will specify/implement this tag.

At this time, browsers will probably implements native style for this tag and your website's design may break.

So I'm suggesting to use (according to this example) `<img-icon>`.

---

As a matter of fact, the tag `<menu>` is well defined ie not so used, but defined. It should contain `<menuitem>` which behave like `<li>`.

Answer (score 5):

Creating your own tag names in HTML is not possible / not valid. That's what XML, SGML and other general markup languages are for.

What you probably want is

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="lunch">
        <span class="dish">aaa</span>
        <span class="dish">bbb</span>
    </div>
    <div id="dinner">
        <span class="dish">ccc</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or instead of `<div/>` and `<span/>` something like `<ul/>` and `<li/>`.

In order to make it look and function right, just hook up some CSS and Javascript.

Comment: No, it isn't. SGML was made for this long before XML was on the scene.

Comment: Is anyone using plain SGML today? Either people use HTML or XML and many of it's descendants, but i've never seen SGML in the wild! Anyways, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I bet there are still some people using Docbook SGML for documentation.  There certainly were lots just a few years ago.

Answer (score 5):

As Michael suggested in the comments, what you want to do is quite possible, but your nomenclature is wrong.  You aren't "adding tags to HTML 5," you are creating a new XML document type with your own tags.

I did this for some projects at my last job.  Some practical advice:

1. When you say you want to "add these to HTML 5," I assume what you really mean is that you want the pages to display correctly in a modern browser, without having to do a lot of work on the server side.  This can be accomplished by inserting a "stylesheet processing instruction" at the top of the xml file, like <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="menu.xsl"?>.  Replace "menu.xsl" with the path to the XSL stylesheet that you create to convert your custom tags into HTML.
2. Caveats: Your file must be a well-formed XML document, complete with XML header <xml version="1.0">.  XML is pickier than HTML about things like mismatched tags.  Also, unlike HTML, tags are case-sensitive.  You must also make sure that the web server is sending the files with the appropriate mime type "application/xml".  Often the web server will be configured to do this automatically if the file extension is ".xml", but check.
3. Big Caveat: Finally, using the browsers' automatic XSL transformation, as I've described, is really best only for debugging and for limited applications where you have a lot of control.  I used it successfully in setting up a simple intranet at my last employer, that was accessed only by a few dozen people at most.  Not all browsers support XSL, and those that do don't have completely compatible implementations.  So if your pages are to be released into the "wild," it's best to transform them all into HTML on the server side, which can be done with a command line tool, or with a button in many XML editors.

Answer (score 5):

Custom tags can be used in Safari, Chrome, Opera, and Firefox, at least as far as using them in place of "class=..." goes.

green {color: green} in css works for

```
<green>This is some text.</green>
```

Comment: You are correct @chas but this method is not recommended, and it will will come under the category of "Hacks and Tricks"...

Answer (score 3):

```html
<head>
  <lunch>
    <style type="text/css">
      lunch{
        color:blue;
        font-size:32px;
        }
      </style>
    </lunch>
  </head>

<body>
  <lunch>
    This is how you create custom tags like what he is asking for its very simple just do what i wrote it works yeah no js or convoluted work arounds needed this lets you do exactly what he wrote.
    </lunch>
  </body>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Any idea why this has not been upvoted or accepted?

Comment: there is a problem with this and it is called forward compatibility. who knows if someone at W3c decides in  2054  the tag `<lunch>` gets included in the standard to induce the smell of Pizza (default ) and you were designing a page for a cajun restaurant . To prvent trouble use `<main-dish>` (two wordl instead) .

Answer (score 2):

For embedding metadata, you could try using [HTML microdata](http://dev.w3.org/html5/md/), but it's even more verbose than using class names.

```
<div itemscope>
    <p>My name is <span itemprop="name">Elizabeth</span>.</p>
</div>

<div itemscope>
    <p>My name is <span itemprop="name">Daniel</span>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Update of link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_microdata.htm

Answer (score 2):

Besides writing an XSL stylesheet, as I described earlier, there is another approach, at least if you are certain that Firefox or another full-fledged XML browser will be used (i.e., NOT Internet Explorer). Skip the XSL transform, and write a complete CSS stylesheet that tells the browser how to format the XML directly.  The upside here is that you wouldn't have to learn XSL, which many people find to be a difficult and counterintuitive language.  The downside is that your CSS will have to specify the styling very completely, including what are block nodes, what are inlines, etc.  Usually, when writing CSS, you can assume that the browser "knows" that <em>, for instance, is an inline node, but it won't have any idea what to do with <dish>.

Finally, its been a few years since I tried this, but my recollection is that IE (at least a few versions back) refused to apply CSS stylesheets directly to XML documents.

Comment: Yeah, I think IE goes into a special XML rendering mode, and pretty much shows you a prettified, collapsible version of the XML document.

Answer (score 2):

The point of HTML is that the tags included in the language have an agreed meaning, that everyone in the world can use and base decisions on - like default styling, or making links clickable, or submitting a form when you click on an `<input type="submit">`.

Made-up tags like yours are great for humans (because we can learn English and thus know, or at least guess, what your tags mean), but not so good for machines.

Answer (score 2):

In some circumstances, it may look like creating your own tag names just works fine.
However, this is just your browser's error handling routines at work. And the problem is, different browsers have different error handling routines!

See this example.
The first line contains two made-up elements, `what` and `ever`, and they get treated differently by different browsers. The text comes out red in IE11 and Edge, but black in other browsers.
For comparison, the second line is similar, except it contains only valid HTML elements, and it will therefore look the same in all browsers.

```css
body {color:black; background:white;} /* reset */

what, ever:nth-of-type(2) {color:red}
code, span:nth-of-type(2) {color:red}
```

```html
<p><what></what> <ever>test</ever></p>

<p><code></code> <span>test</span></p>
```

Another problem with made-up elements is that you won't know what the future holds. If you created a website a couple of years ago with tag names like `picture`, `dialog`, `details`, `slot`, `template` etc, expecting them to behave like spans, are you in trouble now!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an option in any HTML specification :)

You can probably do what you want with `<div>` elements and classes, from the question I'm not sure exactly what you're after, but no, creating your own tags is not an option.

Comment: It is an option now: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/custom/index.html

Answer (score 1):

As Nick said, custom tags are not supported by any version of HTML.

But, it won't give any error if you use such markup in your HTML.

It seems like you want to create a list. You can use unordered list `<ul>` to create the rool elements, and use the `<li>` tag for the items underneath.

If that's not what you want to achieve, please specify exactly what you want. We can come up with an answer then.

Comment: It won't give you an error in the browser, but IE handles CSS on unknown tags oddly.

Comment: Hmmm, now I didn't know that! I knew that the unknown CSS names are handled oddly (that's an error). But, are you sure it handles the unknown tags oddly too? Doesn't it just render them without the text in the `<>` tags?

Comment: you can’t apply CSS to unknown elements in Internet Explorer. Try styling an `<abbr>` element in IE 7. It won’t work, because IE 7 didn’t implement `<abbr>` (even though it’s in the standard!). I have a grim little chuckle to myself when people blindly say that non-standard code won’t cause any errors. How the heck do you know it won’t cause any errors? It’s hard enough getting standard code to work, let alone non-standard code.

Comment: Paul, look to the html5shim for your solution.
You won't get the benefit of custom-functionality, but if you're looking for a container, all you need to do is pop a document.createElement("MyNewTagName"); into the head (or at least above where you want any styled version of that tag to be).

Even create an array of them, and iterate through, creating them in JS -- no DOM-attachment needed, just create one and chuck it.

Just be prepared to style them as if they were block-layout and 100% unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom attribute through HTML 5 data- Attributes.
For example: Message
That is valid for HTML 5. See http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ to get details.

Answer (score 1):

[Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) or [X-tags](http://x-tags.org/) allow you to build your own html tags. It is based on native browser's "shadow DOM".

Answer (score 1):

You can just do some custom css styling, this will create a tag that will make the background color red:

```css
redback {background-color:red;}
```

```html
 

<redback>This is red</redback>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyExample</title>
  <style>
    bloodred {color: red;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <bloodred>
    this is BLOODRED (not to scare you)
  </bloodred>
</body>
<script>
  var btn = document.createElement("BLOODRED")
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this article on creating custom HTML tags and instantiating them.  It simplifies the process and breaks it down into terms anyone can understand and utilize immediately -- but I'm not entirely sure the code samples it contains are valid in all browsers, so caveat emptor and test thoroughly. Nevertheless, it's a great introduction to the subject to get started.

[Custom Elements : Defining new elements in HTML](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)