# Strange html syntax

Tags: html

In the code I am working on I found this:

```
<div class="icon icon2  screen-icon" data-screen-idx=1>
```

What puzzles me is the last "attribute" (or whatever it is )
Is this `data-screen-idx-1` legal in html tag?
Please note that `1` is not quoted.

If yes, where can I find info about this.
If not, why would someone write such thing?

Comment: this can be easily googled and is perfectly valid html

Comment: This is possible with HTML5. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164000/how-can-i-create-my-own-html-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is valid HTML. They are called "data-attributes" and can be whatever you want, as long as they begin with `data-`.

See this article for more information. [MDN - Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)