# What is the <list> tag?

Tags: html

I was looking at Chrome's page source for its beautiful saved password management in its preferences. In it, I saw the following code:

```
<list id="saved-passwords-list" class="settings-list" tabindex="0">
<div class="spacer" style="height: 0px; "></div>
[...]
</list>
```

What is the `<list>` element? I didn't see it in any directory of HTML tags, or after some Googling. Maybe it's a Chrome-specific tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a "create your own tag" situation.

This might be helpful: [Is there a way to create your own html tag in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5)

Comment: Woah, I never knew that was possible. I checked the stylesheet and it appears that the `<list>` element is just being used as a shortcut for a block element. I.e. `<div class="list">` probably would have worked just as well.