# Custom Tags in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, custom-tag

I'm having issues getting my font style to appear correct in IE8.  It looks fine in all other browsers.

For example, on this page the title "Acai Berry" has a  tag:
http://www.ultralaboratories.com/Fruitrients/Acai%20Berry/index.php

In mys CSS file, h10 looks like this:

```
h10 {
font-size: 2em;
color: #000;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bolder;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

In IE8 it's not styling it properly; it's not bolded or large text.  All other fonts appear to be fine.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Have you checked the styling in the development tools?

Comment: h10 is not a valid HTML element.  Does the page pass validation?

Comment: You should consider using your H tags properly, it's good for SEO, and stops issues like you're experiencing at the moment: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_H35n.html At a bare minimum, consider marking the site title as H1, and removing the H1 tag from your navigation (because it's not the primary heading).

Answer (score 3):

`H10` is not a defined HTML tag. Use a different tag and/or set the class attribute if you want to assign styles to it.

From a quick look at the source of the page, it seems that you are using headings haphazardly (where is `H2`? `H6`?) Do you really have 10 levels of document outlining?

If there really *is* a need to create custom tags/attributes: [Is there a way to create your own html tag in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5)

However, I think the defined set of tags can more than adequately describe your document structure.

I would also suggest [validating your site](http://validator.w3.org), removing deprecated tags like `CENTER` and managing spacing with CSS instead of `BR` tags.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim.  

I'm confused; h10 is defined on line 254 of the CSS.  Shouldn't that apply the style?

And yes, no doubt I've not followed the best practices.  I'm self taught and this is my first site.

Comment: Since it's not a defined tag, the browser may or may not choose to apply the style. IE8 doesn't apply styles to tags it doesn't recognize (at least from what I've seen).

Comment: @Capm,  you cannot create HTML tags with CSS.  They must already be valid.

Comment: Aha!  I got it.  h10 is not a defined tag. I didn't understand browsers can't support any tag you defined and thought it could go on indefinitely.  Thank you everyone for your help!!!

Answer (score 3):

There is no element called **h10** in a valid **HTML** document. Valid headers are: h1, h2, h3,h4,h5 and h6. It's very important for a **HTML** document that the headers follow a hierarchy, such as:

```
<h1>Document Title</h1>
<h2>Document Section</h2>
<h3>Document Sub-Section</h3>
```

This is also very important for **SEO**.