# 2 pixel line different color beside text css

Tags: html, css

Is a simple exercice, probably some solution better than others, but I wonder which is the best to create this kind of structure in html and css:

What I want is the text, then create 2 pixel line, 1px red and other 1 px green.

[image]

Not sure what is the best solution for crossbrowser , want to lines end same time.

Already tried with border, hr , background .. but seems not perfectly finish.

ps-looking for a solution without recurring to a image

Comment: If all else fails, you could just use an image for the two lines...

Comment: was trying not to use an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is to use a simple tag (`<i>` for example) and apply CSS styles to it.

```
<p>Your text <span class="line"></span></p>
```

CSS might look like this:

```
.line {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    * display: inline; /* fix for IE bugs */
    * zoom: 1; /* fix for IE bugs */
    height: 1px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #f00;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00f;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Please respect the semantics. Dont use `i` tag for anything else :) Its not very hard to type `span`

Comment: Seems a pretty solution, still have to check it ... but yes , probably a span should be better http://jsfiddle.net/c4HjQ/2/ Thanks

Comment: @Jashwant that's a fair point :) I'll point out, though, that lots of commonly used libs, such as Twitter Bootstrap, use <i> tag for special things, such as icons.

Comment: for `i` tag and twitter bootstrap, see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/i-tag-for-icons)

Comment: @Jashwant Yeah. Nobody will disagree with you, but at the same time nobody follows the spec completely. Did you know that for years, google.com left out the closing body and html tags because it would load faster?

Comment: and `i` tag allows you to load faster ? :O Hack should be used only when you benefit from them ;)

Answer (score 1):

**CSS:**

```
#lines{
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    border-top: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;  
    width: 100px;
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<span id='text'>My text</span>
<span id='lines'></span>
```

Comment: If you want to reduce the separation between two lines, you can decrease height and `margin-bottom` will take them to vertical center

Comment: With `height: 0px` it's more similar to the example he is giving.

Comment: Good answer, although "inline-block" fails in IE. You'll need a hack for that. See my answer.

Comment: If `inline-block` fails, you can always use `float` in both the `span`. That will work :)

Comment: Btw, `inline-block` is supported in ie >=6 for inline elements. Refer [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my 2 cents... similar to Rodolfo but no spacers

http://jsfiddle.net/c4HjQ/

Comment: agreed +1 on your solution... and change that i to span ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `:after` along with `content`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="linetext">Text</div>
</div>

.container {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 4px solid black;
}

.linetext:after {
    content: "";
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height:1px;
    border-top: 1px solid green;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/wBTqV/

**Documentation**

- CSS `:after` pseudo-selector on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:after
- CSS `content` property on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/content

Comment: Good answer, although not cross-browser (inline-block and :after not supported in older IE's). Also the line itself may be part of the content not just a style, so should be represented in the markup (guessing on that one)

Comment: 1) Shim older IE with CSS PIE, 2) use an image so your site looks right in Netscape 2.0. Choices must be made :) Personally, I am not too interested if people on IE6 are not getting the full experience -- Microsoft has release updates as *critical security fixes* for IE6 to upgrade to IE8. If you are using IE6 still, you're literally a security risk for the entire internet and disowned by the very people who made the browser. Expect a second-rate internet experience. Just sayin' :)

Answer (score -1):

you probably have a 'spacer' image (1x1 transparent image), so you can just do a

```
<div style="float:left">Your text</div>
<div style="float:left">
  <div style="background-color:green"><img src="spacer.gif" width="100px" height="1px"></div>
  <div style="background-color:red"><img src="spacer.gif" width="100px" height="1px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Um, not floats. Or image spacers. Ugh.

Comment: well, you can do it just with dimensions, but I remember having issues cross-browser, like some browsers not showing backgrounds if they were empty, etc.  And he did mention cross-browser option was important.