# Twitter bootstrap : button with only icon inside input-append overflows past the input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I couldnt make up the title clear (feel free to edit it).

So, I have included an image to show the problem.

See the `Google button` is at same level as `input` but `search button` is overflowing.

[image: See the search button overflowing]

Error occurs only when I place just the `icon-search` inside `button`. If I replace icon with text, it fixes the problem. It has something to do with `font-size : 17.5px`  of `.btn-large` when I change it to `font-size:16.5px` , it works. I can hack it but I want a valid method.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chne9/)

**Markup:**

---

```
<form class="input-prepend input-append">
    <div class="btn-group"> <span class="btn btn-large dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Google <span class="caret"></span></span>
        <ul
        class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">a</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">b</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-large" type="submit"> <span class="icon icon-search"></span>

    </button>
</form>
```

**CSS**

---

```
form .input-xlarge {
    padding: 11px 19px;
    /* equal to btn-large */
}
```

**Edit:**

*Experiencing problem in,*

Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57
Firefox 18.0.1
Opera 12.14
(all running in Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/chne9/1/

```
.btn-large [class^="icon-"], .btn-large [class*=" icon-"] {
    vertical-align:top;    
}
```

By default this is set to `text-top` - try settings just to `top` (edit the selector to fit just the problematic button - just to make sure you don't break any other bootstrap functionality).

Comment: @Jashwant - wouldn't really know why they use `text-top` - would have to dig in for this, but no time now :)

Comment: May be because `icons` are usually accompanied by text inside button. Your solution looks good and fixes the problem.

Comment: @Jashwant - probably - still I would apply this fix just in this case (I guess increased font size messes up with the icon alignment).

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap icons are more commonly used with the `<i>` tag.

```
<i class="icon-search"></i>
```

I'm not saying this will fix the problem, however. This could be a browser-specific issue. I know I had issues with IE using `input-append`, but this is nothing a browser-specific stylesheet can't fix.

```
.input-append { height:19px; }
.input-append i { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Edit: This doesn't appear to be an issue on Chrome. At least not for the [examples given](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) on the Bootstrap site.

Comment: I have asked a good question about `<i>` tags in past. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/i-tag-for-icons)

I am having problem in chrome/ff and opera.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `i` since the icon selector in css is `[class^="icon-"]` and not `i`. `i` is used just because it's short i guess and because icon starts with i - using span is much more semantic since it's a neutral element.

Comment: Ah, a great question there! I can't imagine the `<i>` tag here fixing your problem, as I mentioned, but as Bootstrap uses it over `<span>` it's possible that the default span styling would cause this to be a problem. I did test in Chrome and couldn't replicate the issue, but I have seen this before in IE. I think your best bet would be to just create a browser-specific stylesheet to handle it. I've used Bootstrap in 5 or 6 sites now and in all of them I've had to add in a few tweaks for IE (7 especially).