# Should I use the span tag or the i tag for an icon?

Tags: css, tags, icons, html

I'm just curious about which one is better to use in order to add a custom icon next to my links.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><i class="home"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="downloads"></i> Downloads</a></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><span class="home"></span> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span class="downloads"></span> Downloads</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's really cool when the top google results are marked as duplicates /s

Comment: @ScottHillson This question was closed 6 years ago just few hours it's asked because there was already an exact question in the site.. It doesn't matter if it's on top on google now, they are a completely diff website, let's check what bing says then...

Answer (score 14):

`<i>` isn’t the icon tag, it’s the italic tag, and it doesn’t make much difference which you pick. `<span>` is more semantically correct, because it has no semantics.

Comment: Thanks. I see several sites using <i> as an icon tag, why is that though? Is it bad practice? Are they just confused?

Comment: @user2152125: They’re not confused — just trying to be concise, probably. I’d say it’s bad practice, but that’s debatable :)

Comment: They use it because that's what Twitter Bootstrap recommends.

Comment: @cimmanon: I was talking about the Twitter Bootstrap people. People following that advice may or may not be confused =D

Comment: FWIW, that what Twitter Bootstrap *previously* recommended. Their 3.+ documentation uses `span`. Their 4.+ documentation switched things to `svg` elements.

Comment: "<i> isn’t the icon tag, it’s the italic tag" Not anymore. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i

Answer (score 7):

**From the HTML5 spec:**

> The I element represents a span of text in an alternate voice or mood,
>   or otherwise offset from the normal prose, such as a taxonomic
>   designation, a technical term, an idiomatic phrase from another
>   language, a thought, a ship name, or some other prose whose typical
>   typographic presentation is italicized.

Use the span tag if you want to be 'politically' correct.

However, Holly's answer puts up an argument for its use: [Should I use <i> tag for icons instead of <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/i-tag-for-icons)