# How do I center an <i> tag vertically in a <button> tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a button tag like this:

```
<button id="submit" style="height: 30px;">
   <i id="loginLoadIcon" class="spinnerIcon"></i>
   <span>Log in</span>
</button>
```

Which uses css like this:

```
.spinnerIcon {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: transparent url('images/spinnerIcon.png') repeat-x 0 0;
}
```

How do I center the i tag vertically in the button tag?
The button may be resized and the image must keep centered vertically.

Comment: ...why are you using an `i` tag for this icon?

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis... Seems this SO article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/i-tag-for-icons seems to state the `i` tag is acceptable for icons, even though it is commonly considered bad practice.

Comment: Is an inherited html code. The unique reason is because it gives the idea of icon. See Charlie 74 answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
#submit{
  position: relative;
}

#submit::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent url('images/spinnerIcon.png') no-repeat left center;
}
```

?

And no need for `<i>` anymore. You can probably loose the `<span>` tag too, but I don't know how does the rest of your CSS look :)

Comment: I kept the use of <i> tag, with the selector as .spinnerIcon and specified display: block to it with your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CSS **vertical-align:middle** will center it for you.

```
<i style="vertical-align:middle" id="loginLoadIcon" class="spinnerIcon"></i>
```

You can also do it like this though:

HTML

```
<button id="submit" style="height: 30px;">
   Log in
</button>
```

CSS

```
button{
    font-weight:italic;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button#submit {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.spinnerIcon {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: transparent url('images/spinnerIcon.png') repeat-x 0 0;
}
```

this should do it.