# what would cause Bootstrap to insert extra elements into my document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a ribbon overlay for a `<div>` using CSS and Bootstrap's glyphicons.  I'm able to build the ribbon itself with no issues (I think!), but when I attempt to place a glyph `<i>` as the ribbon text, I end up with an extra `<i>` element magically inserted after every `<div>` on the page.  Using regular text instead of an `<i>` works as expected.

[image]

Seen on Ubuntu using Chrome and Firefox.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57Wbd/3/

```
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="ribbon">
      <div class="txt">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

.box {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #808080;
    width: 355px;
    height: 132px;
}
.ribbon {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
    border: 48px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 48px solid #ffe500;
    position: absolute;
    top: -32px;
    right: -72px;
    width: 192px;
    color: white;
}
.ribbon .txt {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
}
```

what might be going on here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org).

The end tag for your `<i>` is missing. Error recovery closing and reopening it so you have one around each piece of all the rest of your content.

You aren't writing an XHTML document served as `application/xhtml+xml` therefore you can't use `<foo />` as a substitute for `<foo></foo>`.

(And [you shouldn't use an `<i>` for that anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/i-tag-for-icons)).