# How do I create an icon like this in CSS?

Tags: html, css, icons

I need to create simple icon in css like this - about 32x32 px.

[image: Icon]

I'd like to make it as simple as it could be (html - no unnecessary divs). The text should be vertically and horizontally aligned to the center of each half.

The text displayed will be short (about 9 chars max, font-size about 10px). It should have static height and width. ALSO The text has to be written in tags (like  or

) so it'd be accessible by CMS.

Here is my solution, which I find wrong, because the height and width is not static:

jsfiddle.net/s2DRr/1/

Comment: where is your solution?

Comment: I made some error with the link to JSFiddle. Now it should be working.

Comment: My attempt at it [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s2DRr/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What's Going On

I use the `i` element to create icons. Normally with an image, or more recently an icon font, but we can adapt for your needs. (Originally the `i` element wasn't used for icon, and it is debatable whether it's semantically correct. However, it's used in many icon fonts, and in some major websites.) Since you need to be able to dynamically place the content in the HTML, we can use the `i` as a wrap, and a `div` inside to make the second color.

### Code

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hyJLz/)

#### HTML:

```
<i>Top<div>Bottom</div></i>
```

#### CSS:

```
i {
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    font-size:10px;
    background:lightgreen;
    text-align:center;
    font-style:normal;
}
i div {
    background:orange;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I'm glad I could help! If this solved the issue, could you mark it as the answer so people reading in the future can find it more easily?

Comment: hello, you should use a valid markup , more like <p>text<span>more text</span></p> :) http://jsfiddle.net/s2DRr/7/

Comment: Yes and no. This is valid markup, because all web browsers, even old ones, will run it. Is it semantic? That is debatable. It's not, with the original meaning of `i`. But if everyone uses it in a way, then that way becomes for all intents and purposes correct. Similar to how the word "awful" started as meaning "good" but now means "bad". Take a look at how Font Awesome does things: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

Comment: Additionally see this answer for much more in-depth arguments on the pro `i` for icon side. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14555422/2111901

Answer (score 0):

You may need to alter the below to match your requirements better, but it should give you a decent starting point:

## [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/CkAS3/1/)

HTML

```
<i></i>
```

CSS

```
i {
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    font-size:10px;
}
i:before, i:after {
    display:block;
    height:16px;
    width:32px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:2px;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
i:before {
    content:'text1';
    background:lightgreen;
}
i:after {
    content:'text2';
    background:orange;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It's pretty cool. But I need the text to be in html, so it'd be accessible by CMS.

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/CkAS3/2/ this uses the minimum amount of elements possible (given that it will be in the context of a layout)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use the css "content" attribute at all. It undermines the sense of dividing style and content. Also I think making the before and after pseudoelements display block is bad practice.

Comment: @DrLudwig3 - I agree, however per the spec, the content style exists for just that...content. The OP didnt clearly state originally that this wouldn't be fixed in which case it is wholly appropriate. If it is to be dynamic then yes it should be separate, `display:block` can be changed to `inline-block`

Comment: Even the update uses 2 `span`s though, and we really only need one inner element. Before the clarification that it needs to be dynamic, though, this is a great answer! Also, we could theoretically combine this with dynamic CSS (style.css.php) and place a variable in the `content:`.