# HTML Section vs Div tag

Tags: html, css

As we are planning to write our own Front-end Framework using HTML5 And CSS3, but The debate with my team is whether to use the `section` tag as outline wrap or not, because [W3.org has not approved the section tag yet](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section).

But, as I went through some debates, I didn't get proper conclusion yet on the usability of `section` tag, hope I will properly conclude on the topic here!

Thanks, and regards

Comment: what does it matter, start with `DIV`, replace it later with `section`.. it's just one second to do search & replace...

Comment: I dont agree, from the OP's link from W3C it states `The section element is not a generic container element` which would mean you will have both `div` elements and `section` elements through out the code. Using each for there specific purposes. Therefore search and replace would be difficult and messy. Better start as you mean to go on.

Comment: Use it and just use a generic CSS reset.

Comment: @vsync ,as you suggested starting with DIV is not a problem , but i just wanted to use it with the right conclusion and complete knowledge of what am doing.and thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can apply the logic of 'common usage make right' which was raised in a slightly different but [relatable question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/i-tag-for-icons) on the use of the `i` tag for icons. Though it is in a slightly different context, the principle is the same. Meaning the `section` tag, whilst may not be technically approved by W3C, it is very widely used. Many WordPress themes and templates use it, and WordPress takes up quite a large percentage of the internet these days.

Before I get stick for saying that, I am not saying use bad practice or use tags when ever for what ever just because every one else does. I mean, if its used semantically, in the right context for the right uses as per the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element) then thats ok.

A `div` tag sometimes doesn't make sense, when you are clearly sectioning an area that has a title and a body of text then use `section`. If you're creating a box in order to put other elements in to section off a part of your page for a menu or comments or something then thats not really the right kind of `section` and so use a `div` or other tags more appropriate.

After all, the SO blog uses them: [image: SO use of section tag]

So does the w3c [website](http://www.w3.org/conf/)
[image: W3C example of section use]

Comment: @friendfx thanks for the edit, is this no longer a draft? - if not ill remove the line about it being one.

Comment: DavidT: not sure to be honest, haven't done the research... the link looks official, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good view to compare section vs div !

We have header, **section**, footer and so on to categorize our page segments.

And each of those segments can have several div tags to make the child elements in the proper place and manner in each segment.

So segmentation is what we suppose to do for good writing , reading and specially for particular net bots which are develop daily to analyse our pages...
While the div tags are important to help to make the proper view of our elements technically and practically.

```
<header>
  <h1> ... </h1>
</header>

<section>
  <h2>  ...  </h2>
  <div>
     <form>
          ...
     </form>
  </div>
</section>

<footer>
  <div>
     <p> ... </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```