# Which element to use for font icons in bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, glyphicons, font-awesome-4

Bootstrap 3 navbar uses glyphicons and Font Awesome icons as shown in html below.
Bootstrap manual recommends to use span element:

```
            <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

FontAwesome web page recommends to use i element:

```
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Using i element makes icon  bigger than using span . Bigger looks better.

Which element should used for font icons ?

```
<div id="sidebar-left" class="col-md-2">
            <div class="navbar-collapse sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked main-menu">
                            <li>
            <a href='OpenInvoice'>
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>Invoice</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

ASP.NET MVC4 is used in server.

Comment: Hi Andrus, look the [FontAwesome examples page](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/), you have some advice for larger and fixed width of icon.

Comment: Thank you. All those samples use <i> element. Can `<i>` replaced with `<span>` safely in those samples ?

Comment: Hi Andrus you can simply use the `span` tag or any other element with `fa fa-_iconName_` class ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using `i` element makes icon bigger than using span

This argument is moot as Font-Awesome's icons are font-based and can be sized manually with CSS's `font-size` property. This means that you can override the size of the icon yourself, regardless of which element you use.

### Which element should I go with?

There have been several debates surrounding which element is best to use (see [Should I use <i> tag for icons instead of <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span)), but ignoring semantics it's important to note that Font-Awesome icons are included within pseudo-elements (specifically `::before`) - so unless it doesn't support the pseudo-element (like the `input`element, for instance), it really doesn't matter which element you go with.

### What does the HTML specification say?

Unfortunately the specification doesn't tell us what we can do with font-based icons, however the key points are:

> #### `<span>`
>
> The `span` element doesn't mean anything on its own, but can be useful when used together with the global attributes, e.g. `class`, `lang`, or `dir`. It represents its children.
>
> ---
>
> #### `<i>`
>
> The `i` element represents a span of text in an alternate voice or mood, or otherwise offset from the normal prose in a manner indicating a different quality of text, such as a taxonomic designation, a technical term, an idiomatic phrase from another language, transliteration, a thought, or a ship name in Western texts.

You can make from this what you will.