# Click on <i> tag that doesn't represent italics but icon

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

Perhaps I have to manage with bad HTML programming (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span)).

In below code `<i>` doesnt represent a word in italics but an icon. Which I want to click but which `WATIR` is suitable for this?

I went to [this](http://pettichord.com/watirtutorial/docs/watir_cheat_sheet/WTR/Methods%20supported%20by%20Element.html) post and I tried `button` and `image` methods but none worked.

I tried it by creating its `page object` (as it is the way I want it to be).

`button(:attendees_list, :title => 'attendees')` and `image(:attendees_list, :title => 'attendees')`

used it as 
`on(UpcomingWebinarPage).attendees_list`

```
<a class="webinar" href="javascript:;">
  <i class="icon" title="attendees"></i>
  <span class="number">12</span>
</a>
```

Comment: @JustinKo could you please take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `page-object`, you'd want to create a generic [element](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/Accessors#element-instance_method). Because this is a strange case, I would use XPath to identify it.

```
element(:attendees_list, :i, xpath: "//i[@title='attendees']")
```

And click it with:

```
page.attendees_list_element.click
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try to use `element` :

```
b.element(:title, 'attendees').click
```