# Links are became unclickable after scrolling down the page

Tags: html, css

Up until yesterday, my links had been working properly. However, I just discovered that if I scroll down the page via mouse or "Page Down", my links cannot be clicked.

It appears to work properly on the mobile versions of Chrome and Firefox, but not their laptop/computer equivalents.

What could be the problem?

```css
header-middle .container .row .col-sm-4 {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.product-image-wrapper{
border:1px solid #F7F7F5;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom:30px;
}
.single-products {
 position: relative;
}
.productinfo{
width: 100%;
height: 265px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.productinfo img{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 130px;
 width: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.productinfo h5{
text-overflow: ellipsis;
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: hidden;
height: 2.2em;
line-height: 1.1em;
}
.productinfo h2{
color: #FE980F;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 700;
}
.add-to-cart {
background:#F5F5ED;
border: 0 none;
border-radius: 0;
color: #696763;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="product-image-wrapper">
    <div class="single-products">
      <div class="productinfo text-center">
        <img src="#" alt="#">
        <h2>price</h2>
        <h5>title</h5>
        <a href="#" target=_blank class="btn btn-default add-to-cart">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
          click now
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check whether some other element is overlapping the links

Comment: We're going to need a bit more code; I just attempted to do this locally, and it worked (Chrome and Safari)

Comment: Aside of your problem, between your `h2` and your `h5`, where's the `h3` and `h4`? You're not abusing headlines for font-size or styling-related purposes, right?

Comment: @connexo, am not getting you. Are you trying to say that it's mandatory to follow that practice? I mean, the `h2`  should follow `h3` and then `h4`, then only `h5` can come in a page, like in that order?

Comment: but my code working perfectly yesterday and still perfectly working localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try two things.

**1.)** Remove use of `<i>` tag and replace with `<span>`

*Check this out:*
[Should I use <i> tag for icons instead of <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span)

**2.)** Your not disclosing all of your code. But maybe your experiencing a `z-index` issue; try setting the [z-index:](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to `z-index: 1001;` on your `.btn` class (or whatever z-index value works)

**Note://** Also, seems kind of strange your using so many classes on your `<a>` tag. You, should try to clean it up a bit.

*We could be more accurate here if you posted full code.*

Comment: but my code working perfectly yesterday and still perfectly working localhost

Comment: then it's possible something beyond then what you are showing us is at play here