# How to create an icon on the right side of a bootstrap panel?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend, font-awesome

I got a problem positionning an **awesome icon** on a **bootstrap panel**. I want to put this icon on the right side of the panel heading. But the code doesn't work. Can somebody help ?

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Title
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle text-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

If you need to preview the result, check here : http://jsfiddle.net/7q7w0n76/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to change `text-right` to `pull-right` in the `fa fa-question-circle` class.

**E.g.**

```
<i class="fa fa-question-circle pull-right"></i>
```

**Here's the [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/7q7w0n76/1/).**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your CSS file:

```
.text-right {
    float: right;
}
```

If you're using bootstrap, adding class `pull-right` might do the trick as well.

One last thing, if you're adding FontAwesome icons and you write semantic HTML then use `<span>` tags for it instead of `<i>` tags ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11135302/4711865)).

Comment: Could you tell me why should we use `<span>` instead of `<i>` ?

Comment: Using <i> tags is not semantic HTML, fontawesome use this tag because: 1. It's short. 2. i stands for icon.

Comment: Ok. I understand better now. Thx :-)