# Why using <span> with Font Awesome more semantically correct than <i>?

Tags: css, html, fonts, font-awesome

I've been using Font Awesome for a while and I wonder one thing which tag should I use for it.

[Here](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) is said that they like the `<i>` tag for brevity, but using a `<span>` is more semantically correct.

I read [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html) for [`<i>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element) and [`<span>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element). Unfortunately, I can't find the difference, they're both have the same context in which they can be used.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between `<span>`  and `<i>` is that `<i>` was originally intended for *italics* font, while `<span>` is intended to encapsulate a piece of content **without** changing any css rules immediately. In other words, `<span>` can be used for any custom css action you want to apply.

Therefore, from a theoretical and historical perspective, `<span>` would be a more proper choice.

However, `<i>` is much shorter and the effect in the browser is identical, so choose `<i>` in order to optimize your page speed with a few microseconds, and your coding speed with a few seconds.

Comment: From the Font Awesome site:

[https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/web-fonts-with-css]

**Basic Use**
You can place Font Awesome icons just about anywhere using a CSS style prefix and the icon’s name. Font Awesome is designed to be used with inline elements (we like the <i> tag for brevity, but using a <span> is more semantically correct).

Answer (score 3):

It is because `<i>` is for italic text in html and `<span>` can contain any inline element. Thus using `span` instead of `i` is more semantically correct. But still `<span>` is also not denoting for using icons in html, so this is also not more semantically correct until you add a role as img like this:

```
<span class="your_awesome_font_icon" role="img"></span>
```

Comment: Specification has a note about it: Style sheets can be used to format i elements, just like any other element can be restyled. Thus, it is not the case that content in i elements will necessarily be italicized.

Comment: But talking semantically we would just see html not css. Also note, google search engine works with html only not css.

Comment: Thank you. I like your idea using <span> with role='img'. I've never heard about it.