# Font Awesome <i> </i> tag's - Nibbler

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm looking for some help on something that I'm really struggling to get my head around.

I've ran my website through Nibbler and I'm seeking a 10/10 mark on all (if not most) of the categories.

One thing that I'm really struggling with is the 17 occurrences of Font Awesome `<i>` tag's that it suggests I shouldn't be using.

As far as I'm aware, the proper syntax from FA's documentation should be:

```
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
```

The guidance on Nibbler suggests:

> 2 pages of this website were found to be using the tag <i>. It is widely regarded that use of presentational elements like <i> should be avoided.
>
> Replace all the instances of presentational tags with a semantic alternative. This means where possible, use semantically correct HTML and then style it with CSS.

It's only a 2 page website so far but if I continue working with the same practice, more instances are going to flag up, so I'd really prefer to find some help with a fix before I go any further.

Does any one have any suggestions on alternate ways around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span

Comment: did you link font-awesome to your page

Comment: Give your website link please if possible.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that FontAwesome has hijacked the intent of the <i> element to give it a different meaning than it has according to the W3C.

Answer (score 8):

You could replace

```
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
```

with

```
<span class="fa fa-check"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I've upvoted the answer (being a new member it won't show just yet though from what I understand).

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work and do like this.try with link `font-awesome` online .try this

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>fa</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



</head>

<body>
<i class="fa fa-check"></i><input type="text"/>

</body>
</html>
```

link `font-awesome` style sheet online by adding  this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

between end `<title>` and end `<head>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

add [`aria-hidden="true"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden) to your `<i>` tag or `<span>` tag

```
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).