# How do I select a nested html i tag?

Tags: html, css

My code consists of the following:

```
<div class="site-logo">
  <a href="https://www.fakedomain.net/index.php/" class="site-logo-link">
    <span class="site-logo-icon">
      <i style="background-image:url(https://www.fake.net/logos/image.png)"></i>
    </span>
      <span class="site-logo-name" style="display:none;">asdfasdf</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I'm attempting to resize the height background image of the i tag to 100px.  I realize that I could insert an inline style to the i tag; however, I would rather change the height from within a .css file.  I tried without success:

```
.site-logo-icon i {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Inline elements have no height. Your CSS selector is correct, but it won't be applied unless you change the display to block

Comment: I would strongly advise using a more appropriate element here - either `<img>` or just adding a background to the span or the div itself. The `<i>` tag [isn't meant to be used for icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span).

Comment: I agree.  I'm using a social network php script and I scratched my head after I dove into the code and saw that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **inline-block** to allow use of a height and width.

You should also put the background image in the CSS, or use an **img** tag.

```
.site-logo-icon i {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    background-image:url('https://www.fake.net/logos/image.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the i tag as a block level element:

```
.site-logo-icon i {
     display: block;
}
```