# why <i> tag usually used in icons?

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome

I think that the question is clear, why is  tag usually used in icons pack?

e.g. font awesome, bootstrap or google.

thanks for the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use <i> tag for icons instead of <span>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span)

Answer (score 1):

Because it's the shortest one ;) Instead you can use span.