# CSS Check if icon (i) comes before or after text inside a button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how I can check with CSS if inside a button, an icon comes before or after the text, so I can manipulate it.

For example:

```
<a href="#" class="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>TEXT</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" class="button">TEXT<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
```

How can I manipulate the size of the icons, depending on the position relative to the text?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. But why don't you just use two different classes? "fa fa-plus before" and "fa fa-plus after"?

Comment: @Secespitus I could, but it's one extra step - if there's a built in solution, that's of course better :)

Comment: Or, simply remove `<i>` altogether and instead style your `<a>` with some `padding-left` and `background-image` to show the appropriate icon? I don't really understand the whole *`i` for icon* trend, to be honest (also [see this comment by deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span#comment20308267_14555422)).

Comment: Essentially, you can't. **Text** is not an element and so cannot be selected by CSS. You would need javascript or change the HTML as suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap the text  with a `span` and you can do that

```css
a {
  display: block
}

a>span:first-child {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#" class="button"><span>TEXT</span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>

<hr />

<a href="#" class="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>TEXT</span></a>
```

Comment: But does this let him style the *icon* differently based upon its position or just the span/text itself?

Comment: @domdom, just use `i:first-child` and `i:last-child` to style them differently