# CSS Sprite Sheet using multiple backgrounds

Tags: html, css

I'm using a CSS Sprite Sheet technology and have a problem with multiple backgrounds.

In this website - https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_img you can see how to set a background from a sprite sheet but my case is a bit different.

Simple code:

```css
#nav1 {
  background: url(https://n3olukas.000webhostapp.com/images/nav-icons.png) -165px -19px no-repeat, url(https://n3olukas.000webhostapp.com/images/x3_1.png) no-repeat;
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  background-size: 319px 349px, auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav1"></div>
```

And the problem is I don't want to show these 2 icons. I want to show only the first one:
[image]

How could I make it? I've tried height and width properties but I think it's not for multiple backgrounds.

Comment: How do you want to show it? Cropped?

Comment: Yes, I guess. I want to remove these 2 icons and show only the first one. This effect is like height or width does but I can't use it in the multiple background :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to crop each image in a multiple-background setting separately. So if you want to keep the yellow bar, but only show one icon on it, consider using a pseudo-element, or an actual DOM element reserved to displaying single icons. E.g. here with an `<i>`:

```css
#nav1 {
  background: url(https://n3olukas.000webhostapp.com/images/x3_1.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
}

i.icon1 {
  background: url(https://n3olukas.000webhostapp.com/images/nav-icons.png) -165px -19px no-repeat;
  background-size: 319px 349px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav1"><i class="icon1"></i></div>
```

If you want to make sure it stays in the background, use `z-index`. If you want to make sure it doesn't interfere with the content of `#nav1`, use `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0` as well.

Comment: Nice answer, thank you. I have one question: why do u use `<i>` instead of `<span>`. Is it better?

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis No, there is no real reason, other than a "convention" set by Font Awesome. The reason they use `<i>`, AFAIK, is because it is only one character long and you could say it stands for "icon".

Comment: But `<i>` element means "italic". Is it ok?

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis If you keep it empty, nobody will know :)

Comment: Hehe, thanks. Anyway, I found a good article about this thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span. It seems like using `<i>` is a bad practise but some people use it because of the reasons you said.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to specify a width.

```css
#nav1 {
  background: url(https://n3olukas.000webhostapp.com/images/nav-icons.png) -165px -19px no-repeat;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-size: 319px 349px, auto;
  position: relative;
}

#nav1:after {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://n3olukas.000webhostapp.com/images/x3_1.png) no-repeat;
  width: 232px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav1"></div>
```

Comment: It crops yellow bar.