# Float: right; Causes text to shrink (Chrome Specific)

Tags: html, css

I am having this issue for chrome (Mozilla works fine) when I `float:right` a specific `span` the text within shrinks. This is only happening on the responsive design mode in chrome, but it also occurs in live mobile version.

There may be an overarching issue. In the first photo, the icon and text is squished together, and this doesn't happen in firefox or in regular chrome.

Here is a picture **without** the float right.

[image: Without float right]

Here is a picture **with** float right

[image: with float right]

Here is the abridged HTML

```
<div class="post-footer">
    <span class="tag"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i>music</span>
    <span id="date" class="tag"><i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i>June 7th, 2018</span>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.post-footer {
  padding: 15px;
}

.post-footer .tag {
  border-radius: 200px;
  background-color: #c0392b;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.post-footer .tag i {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#date {
  background-color: #27ae60;
  float: right;
  padding: 2px 12px;
}
```

Any ideas to why chrome is acting this way? Is there a wiki or guide to common browser bugs?

EDIT: The site seems to work fine on an iPhone in safari and chrome. It does not work a S9 with Chrome.

[The complete code can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/karadshf/bg19hp5x/)

Comment: `Is there a wiki or guide to common browser bugs?` I don't think there is such a thing, but the closest thing I know is https://www.caniuse.com/

Comment: Is the `<i>` tag really appropriate? [Should I use <i> tag for icons instead of <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Hmm, I have never heard of this topic, but I will look into it. I'm not sure if FontAwesome supports `span`? EDIT: Well, `span` works fine for FA

Comment: Have you made sure your Chrome is up to date? I am running your jsfiddle, but it seems to run great and look exactly how you want it, with no shrinking. [Picture from my Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVlRY.png)

Comment: When you float it, the `span` that's normally a `display: inline` element becomes a `display: block` element and the padding gets calculated different

Comment: I just updated chrome, and this issue still persist.  The live version on mobile had chrome installed yesterday. Also, did you copy and paste the code into new files?

Comment: @zgood That actually explains a problem I was having a while back, but it doesn't seem to make a difference at the moment.

Comment: @FaridKaradsheh I see the same thing in my Chrome, everything looks fine no issue. Try disabling some Chrome extension maybe and see if something is interfering. Maybe try viewing on a different PC

Comment: @zgood I just disabled all themes and extensions and went to a windows PC (was on ubuntu before), and the issue still persists for me. You viewed it outside of the fiddle correct? This is odd.