# Vertical icon button navigation without font awesome

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a vertical left navigation menu.  It has 8 icons with text right beneath the icons.  I cannot use any icon font toolkit or libraries.  I was given the 8 icons in png format so that is what I have to work with.  I have been reading online the do and don't and arguments against using "i" tag but I'm not sure where to begin/end with this.  I went to W3schools and even the article there on vertical menu is using font awesome.

How can I replicate this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_icon_bar.asp without font awesome and text beneath the icon of the button?

Based on the respone I feel the need to include the link I am trying to referring to about the  tag.

[Should I use <i> tag for icons instead of <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span)

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code snippet, all explanations are in the css. I hope this gives you the answer you needed, I know you wanted to know if you should use  or  but this should work.
As for SEO (Search Engine Optimization) this should be fine since you have an `a` tag.

```css
/*This is a vertical nav bar that will take the whole height, the width of it isn't fixed since the text might take space so it has to expand as needed*/
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

/*The vertical nav bar*/
.container { 
  height:100%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}



/*put it as <a> to link it to somewhere else, this wraps the image and the text together*/
a.wrapper{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  /*Flex column to align the image and the text underneath each other*/
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding:5px;
  margin-bottom:15px; 
}

a.wrapper:hover{
  background: green;
}

.container .wrapper .img-wrapper{
  /*Having an image container with a fixed width and the image itself at 100% width is the best thing you could do for images, because the image will take the needed height to not lose any img clarity*/
  width:30px;
  
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.container .wrapper img {
  width:100%;
}

.container .wrapper p {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="wrapper" href="https://google.com">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/ps.png">
    </div>
    <p>Item 1</p>
  </a>
  
  <a class="wrapper" href="https://google.com">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/ps.png">
    </div>
    <p>Item 1</p>
  </a>
  
  <a class="wrapper" href="https://google.com">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/ps.png">
    </div>
    <p>Item 2929292</p>
  </a>
  
  
</div>
```