# jQuery class on click works on desktop but not mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have FontAwesome icons with class='className'.

```
<i class="className fas fa-circle"></i>
<i class="className fas fa-circle"></i>
```

and the below jQuery script.

```
$(document).on('click', '.className', function () {
    console.log('working');
});
```

It works fine on desktop but is unresponsive on my iPhone SE Safari browser.

edit: added closing tags, just forgot to add them here, I'm using i, as that is what the FontAwsome site uses?

Comment: Are you looking at the browser console via Safari on a connected Mac?

Comment: Sometimes the icons are just too small in order for a touch event to be registered on an non *active link* element. Any CSS / HTML to share? Otherwise I'll just guess your icons are 300x300px large and everything works.

Comment: Also `<i class="className fas fa-circle"><i class="className fas fa-circle">` is broken HTML... at least without some `</i>`

Comment: Try closing `<i>` tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had jQuery UI loaded, no longer using, removed it and now pressing the  tags works.

I assume if I left jQuery UI and wrapped the  tags with a  tag it may have worked?

in any case I also used old mates method of selecting the wrapper, not the document.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bind to the document, bind to a wrapper of the icons.  Not sure why you used the "italic" or stand off element so I changed to a span:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i

```js
$("#myicons").on('click', '.className', function() {
  console.log('working');
});
```

```html
<div id="myicons">
  <span class="className fas fa-circle" />
  <span class="className fas fa-circle" />
</div>
```

Comment: The `<i>` element is often used for Font Awesome.

Comment: @Twisty Perhaps, but does not make it "right" IMHO, seems a bit "hijacked"

Comment: Incidentally, see [Should I use <i> tag for icons instead of <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span)

Answer (score 0):

Would test with the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.className', function() {
    console.log('working');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="className fas fa-circle"></i>
<i class="className fas fa-circle"></i>
```

There should be no issue with testing on Mobile versus Desktop. Unless you have some conditional statement that loads different Libraries for Mobile.

If you need further help, please a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).