# How to place multiple icons next to containers in a grid layout with six boxes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have a three column two row grid layout with a total of six containers on 2 lines, three boxes on each row. I want to place icons outside the boxes next to each box inline with the heading.

I have a div section for the grid which is class= "row" and a div within that for the columns. I have tried creating a class for the icons within the row div but before each column div. The icons unfortunately don't appear outside the corresponding boxes, instead they appear in the top right hand corner

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 22%;
  margin-left: 115px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: black;
  height: 270px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.row.i:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="section section-dark">

  <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    <div class="column"><i class="fal fa-address-card"></i>
      <div class="column"><i class="fas fa-alarm-snooze "></i>
        <div class="column "><i class="fad fa-alicorn"></i>
          <div class="column">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Results are disappointing as stated above not much happens except that the icons appear in the top right hand corner.

Comment: you are nesting your columns - is this intentional or a copy and paste error?

Comment: Copy and paste error

Comment: Technically, the `<i>` element should contain phrasing content "(not only consisting of white spaces characters)."  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content but has been hijacked here to improperly be "icon" instead of semantic meaning

Comment: @CodeJunky Where do you want the icons to be positioned?

Comment: @brooksrelyt  common perhaps but  "standard" no, it is not according to the HTML spec  a standard. Use still does not match specification related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11135261/125981

Comment: @brooksrelyt I am new at this, struggling my way through it so perhaps I haven't explained myself very well. I am trying to position the icons next to each box but outside the boxes in line with the headings. The icons are in some way a representation of the content of the boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to double check your HTML. Many of your divs were left open and one icon was outside of your column making it harder to position.

But, to solve it, add spacing to your `i` icon. Like this:

```
i {
    left: -30px;
    position: relative;
}
```

This will move the icon to the desired location. I think.

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 22%;
  margin-left: 115px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: black;
  height: 270px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

i {
  left: -30px;
    position: relative;
}
.i:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="section section-dark">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></div>
    <div class="column"><i class="fal fa-address-card"></i></div>
    <div class="column"><i class="fas fa-alarm-snooze "></i></div>
    <div class="column "><i class="fad fa-alicorn"></i></div>
  </div>
</section>
```