# Codacy says I have style information in my JSP files, but I don't see any. What am I missing?

Tags: html, css, codacy

I am running codacy on my JSP files and am getting the following error:

> Avoid having style information in JSP files.

Strangely, it's giving me the following code as the problematic code, but I don't see anything that would be causing this issue. Unless it's type="button". Can someone help?

[image: See image for the problematic code]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11135302/19068

Answer (score 0):

`i` is for italicization. That's styling.

Comment: * is for italicization, i is for icon.

Comment: For HTML, when the message mentions the HTML B and FONT tag names?

Comment: @RomanC — `*` has no special meaning in HTML. `<i>` is for [a span of **text** in an alternate voice or mood, or otherwise offset from the normal prose in a manner indicating a different quality of text, such as a taxonomic designation, a technical term, an idiomatic phrase from another language, transliteration, a thought, or a ship name in Western texts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element) (i.e. the kind of things you write in italics and **not** no text at all and a graphic added with CSS)

Comment: (The HTML 5 definition means it isn't, technically, styling, but the testing tool thinks it is and it definitely isn't for purely injecting graphics with CSS so should be replaced anyway).