# $(this).html not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<globemedia id="1"></globemedia>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $("globemedia").each(function(index, value) {
            var globeIDxMedia = $(this).attr("id");
            $.get("getmedia.jsp?mediaID="+globeIDxMedia,function(a){
                $(this).html(a);
            });
        });
</script>
```

The above Script i use to load content to my customized tag say `<getmedia id="1"></getmedia>`

script works fine till getting data from the page getmedia.jsp but when i use `$(this).html(a);` its not loading the data.

**Got Answer from jquery forum**
It'll work with custom tag as well

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("div[data-globalmedia]").each(function(index, value) {
                var globeIDxMedia = $(this).attr("id");
                $(this).load("getmedia.jsp?mediaID="+globeIDxMedia);
            });
        });
</script>
```

jQuery expert gave me solution you have to use `$(document).ready(function(){});` and it works like a charm

Comment: why you are using custom tag ? can't you use any other tag?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/566/ help me with this

Answer (score 8):

Keep a reference to `$(this)` outside the `$.get()` function.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in this fiddle? Please click the check on my answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Run the fiddle you provided me on your own site and see what happens. You can't load a completely different website from another site.

Comment: I tried to run the script on localhost but still its not responding...It load data in buffer but can't append to the `div`

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("globemedia").each(function(index, value) {
        var globeIDxMedia = $(this).attr("id");
        var self = $(this);
        $.get("getmedia.jsp?mediaID="+globeIDxMedia,function(a){
            $(self).html(a);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The meaning of `this` is different within the callback of `$.get` than it is within the callback of the outer `$().each`. You can read more about the semantics of `this` here: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-gotchas/

As a rule, if you want to refer to the "outer" value of `this` within a callback function, you first have to bind it to a variable that is accessible within the callback (in this case, I've used the common convention of a variable named `self`).

Comment: you have `self=$(this)`, then later do `$(self)`...you only need to select it once. i.e make it simply `self = this`

Comment: @nbrooks: true, but jQuery is smart enough that `$()` applied to a jQuery object (the result of a previous `$()`) just returns its argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can't `this` ***( which refers to globemedia )*** within `$.get()` callback function scope. Within `$.get()` callback function `this` refers to something else but not `globemedia`.

So, get keep reference of `this` outside of `$.get()` which refers to `globalmedia` like following:

```
      $("globemedia").each(function(index, value) {
            var globeIDxMedia = $(this).attr("id");

            // keep referece to this
            // ie. globemedia

            var media = $(this);
            $.get("getmedia.jsp?mediaID="+globeIDxMedia,function(a){

                // here self refers to
                // globemedia element

                media.html(a);

            });

        });
```

#### Note

I think `$("globemedia")` should be `$(".globemedia")`. That means you should use a `class` selector.

### You can't make your own custom HTML tag. See **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5)**

As you can't create you own HTML tag (here, `globalmedia`), instead of that you can use `data` attribute to them. For example:

```
<div data-globalmedia="media1" id="id_1">Media 1</div>
<div data-globalmedia="media2" id="id_2">Media 2</div>
```

and so on. And for jQuery you can use:

```
$('[data-globalmedia]').each(function() {
    var globeIDxMedia = $(this).attr("id");

    // keep referece to this
    // ie. globemedia
    var self = $(this);
    $.get("getmedia.jsp?mediaID=" + globeIDxMedia, function(a) {

        // here self refers to
        // globemedia element
        self.html(a);

    });
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/562/)**

Comment: Why he *can't `this` within `$.get()`*? He can but this is just another `this`.

Comment: I'm using `<globemedia>` as a tag

Comment: @SupportTeam  its not working because I think `$(globemedia)` should be $('.globemedia') or `$(#globemedia)`.

Comment: But what if i want to use it as a tag like some html editor use like `<quote>` tag and all.. And one more thing jquery can read its id so it may possible to replace the data..

Comment: @SupportTeam I think `globemedia` is not any valid tag and you can't use that

Comment: Will not work due to Same Origin Policy see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy