# void custom element being altered when calling parentelement.innerHTML to get the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using javascript to transform the DOM, which includes a custom tag (that I can't control the name of).
I then call `innerHTML` on the parent element to get the transformed DOM as a string. My issue is that the simply doing this the DOM changes, I'm assuming because of the custom tag.

See below for a minimal example. Ignore the extra script bit that gets added by the snippet plumbing, the point is that the pagebreak tag now wraps `test`.

How can I prevent this, and preserve the DOM while going through an `innerHTML` call?

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<mbp:pagebreak />test
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect that this question might address the issues you're encountering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700179/html5-define-own-void-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom element is non-void, and so you should specify a closing tag, like this:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <mbp:pagebreak></mbp:pagebreak>test
</div>
```