# What are the reasons NOT to use custom HTML tags?

Tags: html, custom-tag, custom-element

Given current [HTML5 specs](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/) that allows [creating custom HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845124/2066118) (as long as their name contains a dash), and the fact that Web Components seem to be a feature that's here to stay, I'd like to know why is creating your own custom HTML elements frowned upon?

Note, that I'm not asking whether to use Web Components - which are still a moving target, and even with great polyfills like Polymer might not be ready for production yet. I'm asking about creating your own custom HTML tags and styling them, without attaching any JS APIs to them.

Comment: may be identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177472/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-custom-elements-in-html5

Comment: @obiNullPoiиteяkenobi Not a dupe. The question here is about legal and valid HTML5 custom elements (their usage defined in the specs). The other question and its answers don't address this issue.

Comment: just to put some sugar: What are the reasons to use custom tags?

Comment: Each person would have their own reasons. My question was meant to find the real drawbacks of using them. It sure feels odd initially, and that's why most people would be hesitant to implement them, but except for that?

Comment: Chrome at least supports custom tags *without* a hyphen. And why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: I haven't heard any very compelling reasons to avoid them.

However, here are some recurring arguments I've heard made:

- Doesn't work in old IE (just `document.createElement("my-tag");` should fix that).
- Global namespace clashes (same applies to class names, and custom elements in general).
- CSS selector performance (doh, this is just about the last thing you should worry about).
- Separation of functionality, meaning and presentation. This is actually the only argument I've heard that IMHO has any valid basis to it. You're of course better off with semantic HTML (search engines and all that), but if you were going to use a `div` for it otherwise, I don't see why you couldn't use a custom tag instead.

Comment: Wouldn't having custom tags actually contribute to better separation between functionality and presentation though? Instead of divs with classes defining separately presentation and funcion, you end up with an element name that already conveys its functionality and just add presentational class or vice-versa?

Comment: It depends. I've found that as projects get larger, it's easier to contain changes when your styling is in no way related to the DOM structure. You can have two kinds of modal dialogs that are technically both `modal-dialog`, but used in different context, and you don't want changes to one's style affecting the other. So I personally like using classes for styling to avoid styles relying on DOM structure as much as possible and vice versa. I highly recommend reading http://cssguidelin.es/ , it has a lot of good points about this.

Comment: Thanks for the link! While I wouldn't advocate using DOM structure as a main way of determining element's presentation or functions, I believe certain ways of coupling for example parent class to its children layout flow, to be quite beneficial towards code readability and ease of usage. Depends on the case.

Comment: Exactly. These things aren't black and white. I usually go for just styling tags if the use case is simple enough.

Comment: I think none of these would be a problem with a hidden custom element.

Comment: Chrome at least supports custom tags *without* a hyphen. And why not?

Answer (score 1):

One of the arguments against custom tags is their implied incompatibility with screen readers. This issue can be resolved with [WAI-ARIA attributes](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria.php).

There exists an [issue in IE11](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/92c63cd5d88ea9ff75d5d490effb6a0b361e5798), which breaks table layout if a custom element without display property is inserted inside a table cell. [Check the plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/D8TB6MjssIf5xR1sqWw7?p=preview). Therefore, it's the safest to declare all new elements explicitly, for example like so:

```
new-element {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I think this wouldn't be a problem with a hidden custom element.