# Making custom YARD markdown

Tags: ruby, yard

I have the following method that I would like to document using `YARDoc`.

```
# Here is my method
# @arg woop [Woop] *dangerous* this parameter is output to the screen
def shoop(woop)
  puts woop
end
```

This generates HTML where `dangerous` is in bold. Because I have to parse this output, I would like to have a custom HTML tag. In other words, I would like to make it so that when the following code comment is parsed by `YARDoc`, the word `dangerous` is surrounded by `<div class="custom"></div>` tags, instead of `<b><\b>` tags, make it much easier to parse with Nokogiri. Not to say that it is currently impossible to parse with Nokogiri, it's just a bit more awkward and vulnerable to changes in the YARD code.

```
# Here is my method
# @arg woop [Woop] **dangerous** this parameter is output to the screen
def shoop(woop)
  puts woop
end
```

Is there any functionality in YARD that allows me to accomplish this? I looked at creating custom templates, but that seems to be more in regards to parsing code. I then inspected creating a custom markdown template, but I didn't see how this could or should be accomplished. I'm starting to get the impression that I'm barking up the wrong tree and would appreciate a Google keyword thrown my way.

**Why I'm trying to parse the HTML in the first place:**
As I've described in previous questions, I'm trying to define an interface without having to  duplicate code. In this example, I want a server to "call" a method that is dangerous differently than a method that is not dangerous.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why you will need to parse the output? Perhaps there is some way of creating a custom output format that has the data you need, so you can avoid parsing the HTML.

Comment: I've tried, but I'm afraid I don't know how to give much more detail without this question turning into a code review.

Answer (score 5):

Markdown allows you to include inline html. So maybe try:

```
# Here is my method
# @arg woop [Woop] <div class="custom">dangerous</div> this ....
def shoop...
...
```

If this works, you could then override the default css in the `doc/css/common.css` file.

Comment: I didn't know about the css file, so thanks for that, but I would still rather not have inline HTML as this makes my documentation harder to read.

Comment: The other way to do it then is maybe to redefine the `.bold` or `.strong` property in the css file. This way you could use the normal markdown but `*dangerous*` or `**dangerous**` would be formatted the way you wish?

Comment: It's not really the format that concerns me as much as the tags themselves, since I will be parsing this output with Nokogiri for other purposes. I've clarified this in my question now.

Comment: Ah ok. Have a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11467718/2488942) which describes how to handle custom tags from a html point of view. I know you said that you don't like inline html, but this might be a way to get there. You might be able to do something like `<yourtag>dangerous</yourtag>` and define some css for it. Definitely let me know if this works...

Comment: I see now that the custom tag idea was a bad choice. I've now edited my question to just mention custom class tags withing a div, since it provides the same functionality I'm looking for without the Javascript work-around.