# Removing text on mouseout event

Tags: d3.js

Small problem on one viz.
I have a bar chart, and I want it to display some text in the line on 'mouseenter'. That works fine, but I want to remove this text on 'mouseout', and I can't seem to get the hang of it.

Thank you very much for your help!
Attached: the concerned section of the d3.js script

```
    d3.selectAll("div.line")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class","bar")
        .style("width", function(d){return d.occurrence /10 + "px"})
        .on("mouseenter", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d){return d.occurrence + " occurences"});
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
            .select(".text").remove();
        });
```

Comment: Might be simpler to use opacity. `style("opacity",1)` to show text, `style("opacity",0)` to hide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you're trying to select `.text` on mouseout. You're selecting nodes with which have the class: "text" rather than text nodes. Remove the dot.

I'd probably also change the mouseout "select" to "selectall" just in case you miss a mouseout event and accidentally add two text nodes.

Edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/QbGRE/

```
d3.select("div.line").selectAll("div.bar")
    .data(data, function(d) { return d.id;      })
    .enter()
    .append("div").attr("class","bar")
    .style("width", function(d){return d.occurrence /10 + "px";})
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
        .append("text").style("pointer-events", "none")
        .text(function(d){return d.occurrence + " occurences";});
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
        .select("text").remove();
    });
```

Cleaned up your code.

1. "mouseover/mouseout" instead of "mouseenter/mouseout"
2. .select("text") instead of ".text".
3. style("pointer-events", "none) on the text to stop it causing extra mouse events when it's added.
4. Added fake data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
But nope, it does not solve the problem. The text string adds itself to the previous one that did not disappear...

Comment: That works perfectly. And I find the solution very elegant. Many thanks, Glenn.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to assign a unique ID to the new text element and select by that:

```
.on("mouseenter", function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
        .append("text")
        .attr("id", "myText")
        .text(function(d){return d.occurrence + " occurences"});
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        d3.select("#myText").remove();
    });
```

Comment: This seems to work. Although I have sort of a weird blinking, and the text does not display at some point, for some reason. Both with Chrome and Firefox. Do you know what can cause this weird behaviour?

Comment: Hard to say without a complete example. Could be that you're overlaying the text to the `div` and the mouse briefly gets over the text. This way, the `div` would get a mouseout event. Also, HTML doesn't have `text` elements -- did you mean to add that to an SVG?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5. That was one of the things I missed in the jsfiddle example, but it worked anyway.