# Do custom markup tags placed in an HTML document affect the flow and is it possible to parse them with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Would it be possible to do the following

```
<body>
    <main>
        <!-- CONTENT -->
    </main>
    <foot>
        <!-- FOOTER CONTENT -->
    </foot>
</body>
```

if I then wrote some JavaScript that did something along the lines of the following. Please note that I don't want you to write the actual code that goes here. This is just a mockup of the core functionality.

```
for(elem inside main){
    elem.makeItBig();
}
for(elem inside foot){
    if(elem is img){
        elem.makeItSmall();
    }
}
```

I am aware of this post [Is there a way to create your own html tag in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5). But I don't really want to create tags to style them but rather to provide identifying attributes to the DOM which I can hook into using JavaScript. Imagine something kind of like a class, but used in a way that you can stitch lots of PHP generated parts together using these tags.

If you use a made up tag in HTML is it ignored by your browser or will it throw an error.

Comment: Do `data-` attributes not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, good work detective. Link to the question I linked to in my question.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Comment: This *is* a duplicate. The answer is basically the same, whether you would use custom tags for styling or for scripting. The answers to the *ultimate* question may vary, depending on what you really wish to achieve, but this was not disclosed. (It sounds that you would use custom tags just because they are more convenient than classes. But in reality, they are much more risky.)

Comment: I know that you knew this to be a duplicate. Intentionally posting a duplicate is worse than doing so by ignorance.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela if you don't go through the steps listed in the other question do you know what will happen? Do the tags get ignored by the browser or do they render the content inside useless?

Comment: This is no duplicate ... it's just the title that is not pointing to his real problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela alright I updated the title so hopefully I'm clearer. I'm sorry if I was unclear before and for being kinda rude about your duplicate flagging.

Comment: @3boll I just tried briefly and it doesn't seem to work but I'm not sure if that's because it doesn't work or because I'm screwing it up.

Comment: @NickChapman, I think I see what you are getting at, from the title – but now the title has little to do with the body, and it’s still rather vague. E.g., what “flow”? What “parsing”?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, so it's closed at this point but do you know if a made up tag will affect the styles of the things inside it or if it will even be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own tags as far as I'm aware.

You'd need to do some mucking about to get them to work in older IE browsers.

The more important point is - why on earth would you want to? It wouldn't make your code very maintainable or future-proof. Just use classes on proper elements.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create custom tags? yes. Is it a good idea? not really because your tag may not be recognized by some browsers as a valid html standard. you can check this: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_4.html#SEC4.2.1

For custom elements specifications you can look at standards specification for custom elements : http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/

Answer (score 0):

Although your approach seems nice, just think about changing the size of another group of elements ... you would probably use the same function so why not do this:

```
var makeItBig = function(elem){...};
for(elem in main){
  makeItBig(main[elem]);
}
```

this way you won't have to create a new method for each element you need to change.

But if you really need it that way you can make it like this:

```
var makeItBigFunction = function(){var elem = this; ...};
// create new methods
for(elem in main){
  main[elem].makeItBig = makeItBigFunction;
}
// make use of them
for(elem in main){
  main[elem].makeItBig();
}
```

Notice that there is a big difference between DOM object's properties (or methods) and HTML attributes.

- Read more about it: [Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Answer (score -1):

Feel free to use HTML5 tags like `<content>`, `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<aside>` etc.

You can read more about them here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp in section "New Semantic/Structural Elements". Those should be considered as supported in most modern browsers. Actually, you *may* use any other custom tags, however their default properties (display, position etc.) may be unpredictable.