# Custom HTML elements (tags)

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, qtwebkit

I have a question about extending browser based on QtWebkit. I would like to add custom elements tag.
I googled and there was only one way mentioned - using JavaScript registerElement function.

Apart from it I could modify browser to support new tag but I would like to avoid this method.

Is there another approach that allows me on adding new html elements e.g. plugins ?

regards
Jack

Comment: how are you going to use the new tags?

Comment: elaborating on above, depending on how you're going to use the tags, if its just going to be used like any other element (div, etc.) you can just use it, then set CSS for it, as well as other things for browser compatibility and you're done. see the following for specifics  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5

Comment: Please read the following: http://www.w3.org/Style/customdtd There are many reasons to not doing it.