# Creating new html tags (elements)

Tags: javascript, css, html

So we can use javascript to crate new html elements, right?

But if I write in html code:

```
sea{width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue; color: red;}
<sea>This is sea tag</sea>
```

It does make font color red and background blue but dimensions aren't working...
Is that possible only with javascript or not?

Like with new html5 elements (header, footer, section...) is there possible way to create my own names for elements or not?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5

Comment: Probably `display: block;` missing

Comment: @C14L Thank you buddy, that makes a point. Also is it bad to use your own tags for some purposes? Like if I don't want to use inputs and I want to make that my tag content editable to store some info by using jquery and ajax over that beside inputs and staff...

Comment: Link:-https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Answer (score 1):

```css
sea{width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue; color: red; display:block;}
```

```html
<sea>This is sea tag</sea>
```

I think it helps you. Default display block will not come with custom HTML Tags...

Comment: " it increases the accessibility" — It does not.

Comment: yes @Quentin You are right.. even we can give inline anytime.... sorry, I've corrected

Answer (score 1):

> So we can use javascript to crate new html elements, right?

No. You can create new elements, and put them into an HTML document, but they aren't HTML. They don't come with any semantics. They don't have any default styling (including audio styling for screen readers). Don't do that.

> It does make font color red and background blue but dimensions aren't working... Is that possible only with javascript or not?

JavaScript is irrelevant. You'd get the same problem if you generated the same invalid DOM with JS. Browser error recovery treats unrecognised elements as `display: inline` by default. `height` and `width` do not apply to elements that are `display: inline`, you would have to set a different value (e.g. `display: block`) for `height` and `width` to apply.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. For first question as well, I just asked on bad way. But here is a question for you is it good to use our own ones, I read something it is like hacks or something. And if it is bad why so? Thanks

Comment: @BestBudds — I refer you to the first paragraph of my answer.