# css flex direction inside of flex box

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to determine why this doesn't work as one would expect:

```
<style>
holder{
    display:flex;
    border:thin solid black;
}
column{
    flex: 1;
    background:cornflower;
    border:thin solid yellow;
}
holderb{
    flex-direction: column;
    display:flex;
}
row{
    border:thin solid blue;
    flex:1;
    background:yellow;
}
</style>


<holder>
    <column>
        <holderb>
            <row>row1col1</row>
            <row>row1col2<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi<br/>hi</row>
        </holderb>
    </column>
    <column>
        <holderb>
            <row>row1col1</row>
            <row>row1col2</row>
        </holderb>
    </column>
</holder>
```

I am trying to get essentially a 2×2 grid. 
I have noticed that moving the `flex-direction:column` up to `holder` DOES produce this result, but I am wondering why the opposite is not true.

Comment: It's the first flex that holds everything else. Or do you mean the tag itself? It's just a custom tag to make things easier to read.

Comment: Nah, you've been able to do custom HTML tags for a few years now. You do need to tell css how to style them though as they're inline by default. But other than that every browser supports them with no issues.

Comment: @user2182349 it looks like a custom tag which you can use in most browsers.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a 2x2 grid while using items of variable height will inevitably result in something that is uneven-looking. The reason why your `holderb` tag's children do not obey the `flex: 1` property is because you have not specified how much height the `holderb` tag should take up of the parent.

By adding `height: 100%` to your `holderb` tag you can achieve a "grid" that will take up all the space, which might be what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/0uz6txyu

**Edit:** Okay, this one for sure.

https://jsfiddle.net/gcf12eq5/3

Comment: While that is close, it still won't achieve my final goal.
Essentially I want column 1 to always be on the left and column 2 always on the right. Then INSIDE column 2 any boxes to collapse as appropriate.
It could probably be done easy enough with a table, but it wouldn't be as responsive.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "collapse as appropriate". You mean you want the height of the item to be set by the text height?

Comment: See my updated answer for maybe something closer to what you're intending.

Comment: I'm trying to emulate something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/gcf12eq5/1/

Comment: Your newest edit is almost exactly right. The only thing is the left doesn't stay left. I whipped up another example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/0uz6txyu/7/

Comment: That's the most beautiful thing I've ever seen.
Also a lot harder than I thought it would be (in concept). But that's exactly what I was looking for.