# How can I write my own tags? I want to write something like div/span or any other html tags

Tags: html, css

I don't want it to be specific to one project, I am looking for any way to write a tag which can be used globally?

I don't want something like :

```
richa {...styles} [Style.css]
<richa>Contents </richa> [index.html]
```

I want to write it the way, div/span etc are written to be used globally.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Everyone else uses the specified tags, even big companies like Google and Microsoft. Use comments to specifiy your code...

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link for your query.Hope this will help, let me know if this is working for you.
[Is there a way to create your own html tag in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Cool dude, by the way it was a process to use them in you own website, but for globally, please contact to W3, i think they can help

Comment: but i think you should read this document:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html

Comment: document.createElement('mymenu');

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/DPMCM/2/

Comment: You should really try editing these comments into your answer.

Comment: yeah sure, i will try in future, but every html element/tag should be verified by W3 first and then they will add you tag in the new version of HTML, i think i am right most probably