# how to create new tags in html

Tags: javascript, html

so im wanting to create new tags in [html](/questions/tagged/html).
by this I mean like:

```
<imagebutton src="cool.gif" onclick="alert('you clicked the image!')">
<!-- New tag (^) loads an image and lets it have an onclick event -->
```

Im wondering how to do this in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).
is and if so, **how** can I do this?

Comment: one thing to note about custom elements, according to the spec: **The name must contain a dash**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5

Comment: second thing to note: only Chrome, Opera and safari have basic support, and only Chrome and Opera have "Customized built-in elements" whatever that is :p read the specs

Answer (score 2):

Below method is used to create a custom HTML element

```
document.registerElement()
```

Below script would add the following HTML tag to the end of the  element

```
var customElement = document.registerElement('x-custom');
document.body.appendChild(new customElement());
```

Custom HTML Elements

```
<x-custom> </x-custom>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this code :

```
document.getElementById('tag-id').innerHTML = '<ol><li>html data</li 
</ol>';
```

just improve it

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create your own javascript which manipulates your custom html elements and replaces those elements with the desired elements(which do the function). You can refer other frameworks like knockout or angular which manipulate custom attributes and elements.

Answer (score 0):

There's an interesting and in depth article from HTML5Rocks.com on how to work with custom elements : [Custom Elements: Defining New Elements in HTML](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)

Here's an excerpt from the article on how to do it.

### Instantiating elements

The common techniques of creating elements still apply to custom elements. As with any standard element, they can be declared in HTML or created in DOM using JavaScript.
Instantiating custom tags

**Declare them:**

```
<x-foo></x-foo>
```

**Create DOM in JS:**

```
var xFoo = document.createElement('x-foo');
xFoo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert('Thanks!');
});
```

**Use the new operator:**

```
var xFoo = new XFoo();
document.body.appendChild(xFoo);
```