# Can we make our own tag in html

Tags: html

I want to create my own tag such as

```
<store></store>, <market></market>
```

Comment: Both the concepts seems to wrong,https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: use `float: left` for `span` tag or `img` tag.

Comment: @bahmanparsamanesh No, float: left doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: could you please upload your code in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @bahmanparsamanesh Please wait a minute.

Comment: @bahmanparsamanesh [Here is **JsFiddle** link](http://jsfiddle.net/ns9dax8L/1/)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, check out > [Is there a way to create your own html tag in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5)

But it would cause your HTML to become invalid.

A custom tag serves the same purpose as a  tag - it has no direct attribute and does nothing by default, but it can be styled by HTML and accessed by javascript.

Comment: A custom tag serves the same purpose as a `<span>` tag*