# i want to create my own tag such as <store></store>, <market></market>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i want to create my own tag such as

```
<store></store>, <market></market>
```

i want to create my own tag such as

```
<store></store>, <market></market>
```

i want to create my own tag such as

```
<store></store>, <market></market>
```

i want to create my own tag such as

```
<store></store>, <market></market>
```

Comment: $("#desktopicons > div").css("position", "relative").css('display','inline-block'); use this.

Comment: @UllasHunka No, it's not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5), we can create custom tags by normalizing the CSS, and making it work with older versions of Internet Explorer. Please check out the original answer in the link as they discuss some very important points about some issues with making it backwards-compatible with IE6.

In your case:

Lets create  as a custom tag:

First, Reset your CSS:

```
 store{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;}
```

Second, It should also work with older versions of Internet Explorer by appending this to the head:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
 <script> document.createElement("store"); </script>
 <![endif]-->
```

You can use your custom tag, as well as set attributes:

```
<store id="store1" class="storeWest"></store>
```