# HTML, what is an "li-icon" tag or element?

Tags: tags, element

I am a student in Web development and as an assignment, I have to reproduce a LinkedIn profile page with Bootstrap. I have been looking at LinkedIn's code and found an "li-icon" tag or element that is contained in a span tag and containing an svg element. I can't seem to find any documentation on li-icon tags or elements, I don't know what it is exactly.

Here is the code from LinkedIn :

```
<span id="mynetwork-tab-icon" class="nav-item__icon" lang="fr" role="presentation">
    <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="nav-small-people-icon" color="true">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="nav-icon" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M16,17.85V20a1,1,0,0,1-1,1H1a1,1,0,0,1-1-1V17.85a4,4,0,0,1,2.55-3.73l2.95-1.2V11.71l-0.73-1.3A6,6,0,0,1,4,7.47V6a4,4,0,0,1,4.39-4A4.12,4.12,0,0,1,12,6.21V7.47a6,6,0,0,1-.77,2.94l-0.73,1.3v1.21l2.95,1.2A4,4,0,0,1,16,17.85Zm4.75-3.65L19,13.53v-1a6,6,0,0,0,1-3.31V9a3,3,0,0,0-6,0V9.18a6,6,0,0,0,.61,2.58A3.61,3.61,0,0,0,16,13a3.62,3.62,0,0,1,2,3.24V21h4a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V17.47A3.5,3.5,0,0,0,20.75,14.2Z" class="active-item" style="fill-opacity: 1"></path><path d="M20.74,14.2L19,13.54V12.86l0.25-.41A5,5,0,0,0,20,9.82V9a3,3,0,0,0-6,0V9.82a5,5,0,0,0,.75,2.63L15,12.86v0.68l-1,.37a4,4,0,0,0-.58-0.28l-2.45-1V10.83A8,8,0,0,0,12,7V6A4,4,0,0,0,4,6V7a8,8,0,0,0,1,3.86v1.84l-2.45,1A4,4,0,0,0,0,17.35V20a1,1,0,0,0,1,1H22a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V17.47A3.5,3.5,0,0,0,20.74,14.2ZM16,8.75a1,1,0,0,1,2,0v1.44a3,3,0,0,1-.38,1.46l-0.33.6a0.25,0.25,0,0,1-.22.13H16.93a0.25,0.25,0,0,1-.22-0.13l-0.33-.6A3,3,0,0,1,16,10.19V8.75ZM6,5.85a2,2,0,0,1,4,0V7.28a6,6,0,0,1-.71,2.83L9,10.72a1,1,0,0,1-.88.53H7.92A1,1,0,0,1,7,10.72l-0.33-.61A6,6,0,0,1,6,7.28V5.85ZM14,19H2V17.25a2,2,0,0,1,1.26-1.86L7,13.92v-1a3,3,0,0,0,1,.18H8a3,3,0,0,0,1-.18v1l3.72,1.42A2,2,0,0,1,14,17.21V19Zm7,0H16V17.35a4,4,0,0,0-.55-2l1.05-.4V14.07a2,2,0,0,0,.4.05h0.2a2,2,0,0,0,.4-0.05v0.88l2.53,1a1.5,1.5,0,0,1,1,1.4V19Z" class="inactive-item" style="fill: currentColor"></path></svg>
    </li-icon>
</span>
```

Would somebody know what it is? Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 2):

After discussing the matter with one of my classmates, I think I discovered what it is.

It probably is a LinkedIn homemade HTML tag, I did not know you could create your own until I read this post: [Is there a way to create your own html tag in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802687/is-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5). The "li" must stand for LinkedIn.

Unless anybody has a different answer, I think this is the one.